# React.js onClick event returning all null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  click: function(e){
    console.log(e)
  },
  render: function() {
    return div({className: "thing1", children:[
      div({className: "thing2", onClick: this.click})
    ]})
  }
})
```

The event that is passed to contains all the making of a click object but the values are null.

```
Object { dispatchConfig: null, dispatchMarker: null, nativeEvent: null, type: null, target: null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: null, bubbles: null, cancelable: null, timeStamp: null, 22 more… }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

React pools event objects for performance reasons.  So it takes an event object from the pool, sets properties on it, calls your handler, and then sets all of the properties to null so it can be reused.

This is mostly only a problem because the `console` lazily evaluates the object you log.  You could do a **shallow clone** of the event object to make `console.log` work.

For debugging purposes,

```
console.shallowCloneLog = function(){
  var typeString = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)
  console.log.apply(console, Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(x){
    switch (typeString(x).slice(8, -1)) {
      case 'Number': case 'String': case 'Undefined': case 'Null': case 'Boolean': return x;
      case 'Array': return x.slice();
      default: 
        var out = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(x));
        out.constructor = x.constructor;
        for (var key in x) {
          out[key] = x[key];
        }
        Object.defineProperty(out, 'constructor', {value: x.constructor});
        return out;
    }
  }));
}
```

```
console.shallowCloneLog(e)
```

Comment: For simple debugging purposes, calling `persist()` on the event before logging it may be a fine workaround.

Answer (score 22):

Event handlers will be passed instances of `SyntheticEvent`. The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent` object will be reused and all properties will be **nullified** after the event callback has been invoked.

If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call `event.persist()`

```
func(e){
    e.persist();
    console.log(e);// all the properties are retained
}

render () {
    return(
      <div onMouseOver={this.func}>
      //rest of the logic
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using stage-2 or up of the ES6 features `console.log({...e})` would work the same as the shallow clone implementation above.

Answer (score 3):

If you have jQuery handy, simply call:

```
console.log('e: ', $.extend({}, e));
```

Comment: One is probably more likely to have Object.assign:
`console.log(Object.assign({}, ev));`

Answer (score 2):

Using `console.log(Object.assign({}, e));` is an elegant way to handle this--a good alternative jQuery's extend method.

In the interest of teaching a man to fish, it'd be good to learn how this works. Here's the direct link to that section from ES2015 specs: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign